# Syntax Error In JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Im using a custom js which ive coded in a fiddle, and im wanting to integrate it into my wordpress theme: I have used the register and enqueue scripts as below, and they appear to be loading correctly, however it is the custom.js that appears to be erroring.

Please can someone inform me if i have missed a tag or something as i am stuck. Below is my code:-

/***My Functions File***/

```
<?php
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") ."://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui' );

wp_register_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js', array('jquery-ui'), true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );
}
?>
```

/***My custom JS file****/

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("h1, h2").on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).effect( "bounce", { times : 2, direction : "down", distance : "3" }, 200)
});
```

Thankyou
Kirsty

Comment: Please post the syntax error.

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you really tried to solve your problem? Maybe you want to read through [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax).

Comment: [adding proper indentation and spacing](http://jsbeautifier.org/) will help you identify syntax errors tremendously.

Comment: HI jbabey im very new to js, however i have now fixed this, certainly wont be an error i will make again :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to close your document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1, h2").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).effect("bounce", {
            times: 2,
            direction: "down",
            distance: "3"
        }, 200);
    });
});​
```

Comment: And a semicolon after
`$(this).effect("bounce", {
       times: 2,
       direction: "down",
       distance: "3"
 }, 200)`

Comment: Upvote for that. Thanks.

Comment: fab stuff, thanks guys :) it appears to have worked :)